# How to create an alias for operators in ruby

Tags: ruby

> I read that alias keyword is used to create alias for methods,
>   operators and global variables.

**My question is how to create alias for oprators?**

> I am using ruby version: ***ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407)
>   [i686-linux]***

Comment: Your question should be "*Can* an alias be created for an operator?". Most operators are implemented as methods (e.g., [Fixnum#+](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-2B)), so you obviously can create aliases for those. It's just the others, such as `class` and `alias` that are relevant to the question. You can't create aliases for those (without recompiling Ruby), but I don't have a proof for you.

Comment: @caryswoveland `class` and `alias` are keywords, not operators.

Comment: Thanks, @akuhn. What was I thinking of?  Let's say `&&`, `||`, `not` and `defined?` are a sampling of operators that are not methods.

Comment: Those are indeed interesting. Well, not so much `not` which just maps to `!` which can be aliased. Looks like Matz decided to not make `&&` and `||` methods though, maybe to avoid Smalltak's `A.or { B }` syntax? No sure though why `defined?` is not just a function on `Kernel` that takes a string, speaking of which I love that even `loop` is just a function in Ruby. Happy Christmas to you!

Comment: @akuhn: Still Ruby, still a method ;)

Comment: @ericduminil not this one, `loop` is defined using `module_function` on the `Kernel` module. And since `Kernel` is included in `Object` all of its module functions become available as private methods in all objects and thus appear to be global functions. Maybe ask as question so I can expand more? ;)

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome! But you're right, I tend to casually call everything functions. Bad PHP habits, haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example for aliasing `+` :

```
class Fixnum
  alias_method :my_plus, :+
end

puts 2.my_plus(3) #=> 5
```

Note:

The correct, full syntax for `2+3` is `2.+(3)`, because `+` is just a method defined for Fixnums.

It can also be called as `2+3` or `2 + 3`, which is just syntactic sugar. As far as I know, it's not possible to add syntactic sugar to new methods.

Comment: Thanks @Eric Duminil

Comment: the above example works fine but if we try to access like 2 my_plus 3 it thorugh error as:  syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
2 my_plus 3

Comment: Thanks @Eric Duminil